# Sparx EA : detect what database type currently using

Tags: sql, database, enterprise-architect

Is there are way to detect what type of database currenlty is in use as project datasource?

Because I need to get some inner scripts information. And, in case of simple `.EAP` project, SQL-query would look like (because of Access db in use):

`_repository.SQLQuery(string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM t_script WHERE Notes LIKE '*Script Name=""{0}""*';", scriptName));`

But, in case of SQL server I need to execute (as you already guessed I bet) slighly different written query:
`_repository.SQLQuery(string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM t_script WHERE Notes LIKE '%Script Name=""{0}""%';", scriptName));`

So, is it possible?

**UPD**:

I found one option - looks like there are `_repository.ConnectionString` property which could be parsed

> "SparxEaDatabase --- DBType=1;Connect=Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=SparxEaDatabase;Data Source=SOURCENAME;LazyLoad=1;"

Is there are more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just look into `Repository.RepositoryType`. This will return for Example: **JET, MYSQL,** or **SQLSVR**.

Comment: Oh, hello mr. Kilian! Nice one! I was nearly about to stick to `ConnectionString` but your option way better!

Comment: I would have done so too, before looking into my own book (the Repo-File operations) xD

Comment: Damn, I love SO, never could thought that you, mr. Kilian, and, as example, mr. Bellekens, would answer on my questions : )

Comment: Well, you know whats interesting? I cant invoke method throught `Invoke` adn can't compile smth like `string dbType = _repo.RepositoryType()` because of such method signature not found. But during runtime, when I use `Ctrl + f9` and run `_repo.RepositoryType()` it works fine

Comment: Not sure which environment you're using. I'm usually testing things with Perl and a few of the API methods are blocked for such kind of scripting. The Sparx guys once added `GetTreeSelecetedObject` since `GetTreeSelectedItem` did not work.

Comment: Geert is more active on Sparx' forum - and his own blog. But since I'm retired I have more time to answer on Sparx' forums and here :-)

Comment: I use `.NET` environment. Think I have a new question ._.